# Is math.Pow in golang good for this forumla?

Tags: go

Formula:

```
C1*B+C2B^2+C3*G+C4*G*B+C5*G*B^2+C6*G^2+
C7*G^2*B+C8*R+C9*R*B+C10*R*B^2+C11*R*G+
C12*R*G*B+C13*R*G^2+C14*R^2+C15*R^2*B+
C16*R^2*G+C17*1+C18*R^3+C19*G^3+C20*B^3
```

Go:

```
var C1 = -0.0343
var C2 = 0.4062
...snipped

C1*B + C2*math.Pow(B, 2) + C3*G + C4*G*B +
C5*G*math.Pow(B, 2) + C6*G*math.Pow(G, 2) +
C7*math.Pow(G, 2)*B + C8*R + C9*R*B +
C10*R*math.Pow(B, 2) + C11*R*G + C12*R*G*B +
C13*R*math.Pow(G, 2) + C14*math.Pow(R, 2) +
C15*math.Pow(R, 2)*B + C16*math.Pow(R, 2)*G +
C17*1 + C18*math.Pow(R, 3) + C19*math.Pow(G, 3) +
C20*math.Pow(B, 3)
```

All my code works, but I'm seeing values greater than `1` and I should be expecting values in the range of `0` to `1`, so I'm assuming that `math.Pow` isn't what I should be using. New to Go, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Greater by how much? If it's tiny, it's most likely a rounding error, and you can truncate >1 values to 1. Although I would just use `x*x` instead of `Pow(x, 2)` and `x*x*x` instead of `Pow(x, 3)`, most likely faster.

Comment: It ranges on the variables passed in, but its generally in the range of 1 to 4. - Have added output for clarity

Comment: `1.4258552799000002e+07` is a bit outside the range of 1 to 4. Specifically, it's about 10000000 times bigger. I assume you might need to convert RGB to 0..1 from 0..255.

Comment: math.Pow computes arbitrary powers. Computing squares or cubes might be simpler by direct multiplication. And no function can save you from floating point peculiarities. Start by grouping positive and negative summands (do not subtract floats of roughly equal size).

Comment: Your result goes out of range because the `CXX` weights you use, they are also not exact, just truncated or rounded values. So what you experience is "normal". Negate the effect by truncating the result into the `0..1` range.

Comment: @icza: It is not normal. If you have RGB as (1, 1, 1), the result is 1.0011999999999999; that's normal margin of error. If the RGB is (255, 255, 255), then the result is `14258552.799000002`, which is more than a slight error from a value that OP is "expecting values in the range of 0 to 1".

Comment: Amazing help, cheers guys. Converting RGB from 255 ranges to 0-1 produces results I would have expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your RGB values are not in the same range as the formula requires. This formula works with R, G and B components in the mathematically normal range of 0 (darkest) to 1 (brightest), not the usual computery range of 0 (darkest) to 255 (brightest).

Divide RGB by 255.0 before running your formula.

Comment: Works like a charm! Produces far more logical results, cheers @Amaden!

Comment: No, running the above formula with R=1, G=1 and B=1 gives 1.0012 (still bigger than 1). This is what I assumed after the question, so my comments still apply above.

Comment: @izca: As I said above, that might well be the floating rounding (whether in constants provided, or in the floating point operations). The core cause of the problem being 7 orders of magnitude off is not using the right scale of RGB input.

Comment: @Amadan This is too large to be a rounding error. If we change everything from variables to constants (go has "arbitrary" precision in the const "space"), it still gives roughly the same error. This is due to the fact that the used  "weights" are imprecise.

Comment: Oh lord, what have I started?!

Comment: You say "weights", I say "constants". In the mathematical sense, not Go sense. We are not disagreeing. I am talking about `-0.0343` and the rest probably being rounded off from a more exact number, likely a cosine or something.